# Number of people having shaken hands an odd number of times

Tags: problem-solving

This is from a book called USSR Olympiad Problem book:

> Every living person has shaken hands with a certain number of other persons. Prove that a count of the number of people who have shaken hands an odd number of times must yield an even number.

I've got no clue how to even start tackling the problem. I've checked the hints page still don't understand.

Would be nice if you would show me the logic behind this.

Comment: What does the hints page say?

Comment: First show that the total of all handshakes made up to any time is an even number.

Comment: Depends on the definition of "the number of handshakes": with one definition this is trivially wrong and with the other this is trivially right, won't you say? And what is your definition of "the number of handshakes"?

Comment: Can someone like, help me solve it? I came here for help - thanks for the answers and everything but I don't understand the "math" talk.

Answer (score 3):

Each handshake involves 2 people. If the $i$th person shakes hands $n_i$ times, then the sum of the $n_i$ must be even. If there were an odd number of odd $n_i$ then the sum would be odd.

Comment: I've tried understanding your answer but can you please simplify it further? I'm a noob in maths. started taking in seriously pretty recently. after I failed aptitude test for a software company :'(

Comment: Sorry Evgeny, but which part exactly do you want to see *simplified*??

Comment: "If the ith person shakes hands ni times, then the sum of the ni must be even. If there were an odd number of odd ni then the sum would be odd."

Comment: Make up your mind: first quoted sentence or second quoted sentence?

Comment: all of which I have quoted, is what I didn't understand.
translate it to english lol

Comment: So the total number of hands shaken has to be even, because each handshake involves two people. Do you understand this part?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you shake hands you get a euro.
An even number of euro are distributed.
Those with an even number of handshakes between them have an even number of euro
So those that have an odd number of handshakes must between them have an even number of euro
This can only happen if there are an even number of them

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with this is, some living people have shaken hands with people who are now dead. If you  want this to work, you have to either count the dead people as well as the living, or only count handshakes with people who are  still living.

Comment: I am guessing that this is just a stupid formulation (fault of the book, not OP), if you omit the word "living", then all is well.

Comment: What about Siamese twins? :)

Answer (score 0):

All people here have only one hand (that is one confusion kicked out!).
Draw a circle and place  numbers $1,2,3,\dots$ spaced equally on its circumference; to represent the single hands of persons.
Connect the numbers as you wish; each connection representing a handshake. Example: If $4$ lines come out from say Hand $5$, then Person $5$ has had $4$ handshakes; $4$ being the *degree* of Hand $5$. Find the degrees of all the hands. Some degrees will be odd; some even. The number of odd degree hands will always be even. Why? Figure it out. Not difficult.